# R: Pivoting using 'spread' function

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, melt, tidyr

Continuing from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773714/r-pivot-the-rows-into-columns-and-use-n-as-for-missing-values), I am now having 1 more column of ID values that I need to use to pivot rows into columns.

```
    NUM <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1)
    ID <- c("DJ45","DJ45","DJ45","DJ46","DJ46","DJ46","DJ47","DJ47","DJ47","DJ48")
    Type <- c("A", "F", "C", "B", "D", "A", "E", "C", "F", "D")
    Points <- c(9.2,60.8,22.9,1012.7,18.7,11.1,67.2,63.1,16.7,58.4)

    df1 <- data.frame(ID,NUM,Type,Points)

df1:
    +------+-----+------+--------+
    | ID   | Num | Type | Points |
    +------+-----+------+--------+
    | DJ45 |   1 | A    | 9.2    |
    | DJ45 |   2 | F    | 60.8   |
    | DJ45 |   3 | C    | 22.9   |
    | DJ46 |   1 | B    | 1012.7 |
    | DJ46 |   2 | D    | 18.7   |
    | DJ46 |   3 | A    | 11.1   |
    | DJ47 |   1 | E    | 67.2   |
    | DJ47 |   2 | C    | 63.1   |
    | DJ47 |   3 | F    | 16.7   |
    | DJ48 |   1 | D    | 58.4   |
    +------+-----+------+--------+
```

My desired output is

```
+------+-----+------+--------+------+------+------+------+
| ID   | Num |  A   |   B    |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |
+------+-----+------+--------+------+------+------+------+
| DJ45 |   1 | 9.2  | N/A    | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
| DJ45 |   2 | N/A  | N/A    | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | 60.8 |
| DJ45 |   3 | N/A  | N/A    | 22.9 | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
| DJ46 |   1 | N/A  | 1012.7 | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
| DJ46 |   2 | N/A  | N/A    | N/A  | 18.7 | N/A  | N/A  |
| DJ46 |   3 | 11.1 | N/A    | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
| DJ47 |   1 | N/A  | N/A    | N/A  | N/A  | 67.2 | N/A  |
| DJ47 |   2 | N/A  | N/A    | 63.1 | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
| DJ47 |   3 | N/A  | N/A    | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | 16.7 |
| DJ48 |   1 | N/A  | N/A    | N/A  | 58.4 | N/A  | N/A  |
+------+-----+------+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

I am using `spread` function in R but getting errors saying duplicate identifiers. This is because I have 2 columns now (ID & NUM) instead of one (NUM) that I had previously. Please let me know how I could do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing what you've tried, I would suggest:

```
spread(df1, Type, Points)
#      ID NUM    A      B    C    D    E    F
# 1  DJ45   1  9.2     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 2  DJ45   2   NA     NA   NA   NA   NA 60.8
# 3  DJ45   3   NA     NA 22.9   NA   NA   NA
# 4  DJ46   1   NA 1012.7   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 5  DJ46   2   NA     NA   NA 18.7   NA   NA
# 6  DJ46   3 11.1     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 7  DJ47   1   NA     NA   NA   NA 67.2   NA
# 8  DJ47   2   NA     NA 63.1   NA   NA   NA
# 9  DJ47   3   NA     NA   NA   NA   NA 16.7
# 10 DJ48   1   NA     NA   NA 58.4   NA   NA
```

If you are getting an error about duplicate identifiers, it is because the combination of "ID" and "Num" in your actual data have one or more duplicate entries (in your sample data, they don't).

If that is the case, you need to add another column to make them unique.

Adding `dplyr` into the chain, it might be something like:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, NUM) %>%
  mutate(id2 = sequence(n())) %>%
  spread(Type, Points)
```

---

Demo of *assumed* error:

```
df2 <- rbind(df1, df1[1:3, ]) ## Duplicate the first three rows
spread(df2, Type, Points)
# Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 11), (3, 13), (2, 12)    

library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(ID, NUM) %>%
  mutate(id2 = sequence(n())) %>%
  spread(Type, Points)
# Source: local data frame [13 x 9]
# 
#      ID NUM id2    A      B    C    D    E    F
# 1  DJ45   1   1  9.2     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 2  DJ45   1   2  9.2     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 3  DJ45   2   1   NA     NA   NA   NA   NA 60.8
# 4  DJ45   2   2   NA     NA   NA   NA   NA 60.8
# 5  DJ45   3   1   NA     NA 22.9   NA   NA   NA
# 6  DJ45   3   2   NA     NA 22.9   NA   NA   NA
# 7  DJ46   1   1   NA 1012.7   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 8  DJ46   2   1   NA     NA   NA 18.7   NA   NA
# 9  DJ46   3   1 11.1     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 10 DJ47   1   1   NA     NA   NA   NA 67.2   NA
# 11 DJ47   2   1   NA     NA 63.1   NA   NA   NA
# 12 DJ47   3   1   NA     NA   NA   NA   NA 16.7
# 13 DJ48   1   1   NA     NA   NA 58.4   NA   NA
```

Comment: It seems that you don't like `row_number()` as a dplyr substitute for `sequence(n())`..?

Comment: @docendodiscimus, Another function that I have to remember :-) Feel free to edit when I make these kinds of mistakes!

Comment: @AnandaMahto Works beautifully. just as i expected it to be :)